# CSS Raised 3d image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to do an image effect using css or jQuery, doesnt matter. The effect is about, when hovering over an image, this image should go raised like one stair in something like an 3d effect.

I have tried it with borders but doesnt end up like an 3D... Tried to google, found many 3D effects but not this one... Can anyone give some tips ?

Looking after something like this but with images: http://markdotto.com/playground/3d-text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css property `box-shadow` that also allows multiple shadows that will take the form of the element's bounding rectangle.

### Snippet

```css
body{
    background:chocolate;
}
img{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px white,
                4px 4px white, 
                3px 3px white, 
                2px 2px white, 
                1px 1px white,
                5px 5px 5px black;
    border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/animals">
```

### JSFiddle

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y04fckke/) for portability.

### Explanation

A `box-shadow` is defined by `xd yd blur color` where `xd` is the shadow offset in the horizontal axis and `yd` is the shadow offset in the vertical axis.

That way we separate multiple shadows by commas (`shadow1,shadow2`), filling each "step" towards the final shadow width (in this example it would be 5px, so the proceding shadows should be 4px 3px 2px and finally 1px).

To further add to the 3d effect we do one last shadow, this time with a little bit of blur and the color black.

Hope it helps!